# Range slider based on numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

Can you please provide me any references for the range slider based on number like image below. Arrow should be static and range should be flexible for the number. It will be great help. Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 1):

Check this if it suits your requirement.

https://uicookies.com/range-slider-css/

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Instead, flag or vote to close them as off-topic (in this case, A community-specific reason > Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more)